# Convert an input number into a correct decimal output?

Tags: c#

I am a total newbie with almost zero coding knowledge.  Thanks to all of you who will bother answering me.

I have tried to look for that question in Stackoverflow before I ask, but I have not found anything (may be due my lack of experience).

Now, my question:  How can I convert an input number into a correct decimal output?

I have tried with the code below (following a free course of the Microsoft Virtual Academy) but it only works when I remove my variable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string myString = "My \"so-called\" life";
            //string myString = "What if I need a\nnew line?";
            //string myString = "Go to your c:\\drive";
            //string myString = @"Go to your c:\drive";
            //string myString = String.Format("{0} = {1}", "First", "Second");
            //string myString = String.Format("{0:C}", 123.45);
            Console.Write("Insert a number: ");
            var data1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string myString = String.Format("{0:N}", data1);

            Console.WriteLine(myString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again,
Alex

Comment: You can use [`Decimal.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a string to a decimal.

Comment: What do you mean with ``it only works when I remove my variable`` ?

Comment: @RandRandom He's declaring the variable multiple times.  It works after removing the duplicate declarations (commented out in the pasted code).  At least, that's what I surmise he means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I convert an *input number* into a correct decimal output?

We need to be clear in our terminology so let me start there.

You have a `string` that contains a number.  You don't have a number.  `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string.  It may *contain* a number, but when describing the problem, it's important to call it what it is.

It may feel pedantic, but this is an important detail because it affects our understanding of a) your code, and b) what you are trying to do.  Those two things aren't always congruent, and in order to effectively help you, we need an accurate and complete understanding of both.

Thus, your question should be phrased as:

> How can I convert a string containing a number into a decimal?

Now, to answer the question: the act of taking a string and extracting a value out of it is called **parsing**.  You want to parse the string into a decimal number.  With that, you should now know enough to Google.

In C#, you can parse a string into a decimal number by using `Decimal.Parse(...)`.  You can probably guess how you could parse a string into an integer.

In other words, in your case you would use   `var myDecimal = Decimal.Parse(data1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Result of [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) is always string. `string.Format` is not smart enough to convert string value to number and format it if number formatting is requested for string value.

The code needs to be changed to following

```
var data1 = Console.ReadLine();
var decimal1 = Decimal.Parse(data1);
string myString = String.Format("{0:N}", decimal1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers & your time.  :)